# Using CSS3 transforms/animations with font-face produces "wobbly" spinner gif-like

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, css-transitions, css-animations

I'm using CSS transforms/animations with font-face ([twitter bootstrap/font-awesome](http://fortawesome.github.com/Font-Awesome/)) to produce a spinner gif-like icon.

The problem is that the icon wobbles as it revolves around 360degrees. [See this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/timrpeterson/pGhFX/6/) to see what I mean. Does anyone know how to make it **not** wobble? Or at least make it rotate a little more smoothly?

Here's the code for that below:

CSS:

```
i.icon-repeat {
  -webkit-animation: Rotate 500ms infinite linear;
  -moz-animation: Rotate 500ms infinite linear;
  -ms-animation: Rotate 500ms infinite linear;
  -o-animation: Rotate 500ms infinite linear;
  animation: Rotate 500ms infinite linear;
}
@-o-keyframes Rotate {
  from {-o-transform:rotate(0deg);}
  to {-o-transform:rotate(360deg);}
}
@-moz-keyframes Rotate {
 from {-moz-transform:rotate(0deg);}
 to {-moz-transform:rotate(360deg);}
}
@-ms-keyframes Rotate {
  from {-ms-transform:rotate(0deg);}
  to {-ms-transform:rotate(360deg);}
}
@-webkit-keyframes Rotate {
  from {-webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);}
  to {-webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);}
}
@keyframes Rotate {
  from { transform:rotate(0deg);}
  to { transform:rotate(360deg);}
}
#iconRepeatMain{
  display: inline-block;    
  position: absolute;
  z-index:10007;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-left: -24px; /* -1 * image width / 2 */
  margin-top: -24px;  /* -1 * image height / 2 */
  font-size:36px;
}​
```

HTML:

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.1.1/css/bootstrap.no-icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/2.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
<i id='iconRepeatMain' class='icon-repeat' style='font-size:36px; color:red'></i>​
```

**Note:** if anyone wants to use this code in your own web app, please be sure to remove this spinner from the DOM when the action it was needed for is done. Keeping this icon rotating in the background burns up CPU regardless of the browser like you won't believe. Also, simply toggling its visibility, i.e., `display:none`, doesn't work. You need to remove it from the DOM like with this: `$('#iconRepeatMain').remove();`

Comment: That's awesome.  I wouldn't change a thing!

Comment: I assume the problem is that the font isn't perfectly centered itself. Using an image instead might be best.

Comment: @Blazemonger oh that's a good point. Can you suggest a hack to center it?

Comment: @Forty-Two believe me, over time you'll get annoyed with how rickety it looks. The spinner is supposed to convey progress toward success. This looks like a car that is about to have its wheels fall off and go over a cliff.

Comment: I appreciate that this question was asked a while ago but the JSFiddle link no longer works.

Comment: @phuzi thanks for noting that. It works now. I had changed my JSFiddle username which broke that link.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2IHomA2TcJ4

Answer (score 16, accepted):

By default, CSS transforms things about their vertical and horizontal center with the property `transform-origin`. A short-hand syntax for this default value is `50% 50%`, which represents the x and then y value of the origin.

For this icon, I found that shifting the y origin to 38% smooths it out a bit, but you'll need to play around with it to get the precise values. [**View on JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/4VGcZ/)

```
i.icon-repeat {
  -webkit-transform-origin:50% 38%;
  -moz-transform-origin:50% 38%;
  -ms-transform-origin:50% 38%;
  -o-transform-origin:50% 38%;
  transform-origin: 50% 38%;
}
```

For more on the `transform-origin` property, I recommend [the MDN article on the property.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/transform-origin)

Comment: +1 - This is a better solution than mine, in that it addresses the real problem (centering) in the most direct way. Incidentally, `47% 41%` [works even better for me](http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/4VGcZ/1/).

Comment: Other things which I find help with the wobbliness is to use `icon-refresh` instead of `icon-repeat` and to speed up the rotation from `500ms` to `250ms` as shown in [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/trpeters1/4VGcZ/4/). The symmetry of the `icon-refresh` arrowheads compared with `icon-repeat` seems more visually appealing when the icon is rotating. Regarding speed of rotation, usually the spinner isn't noticed b/c pages load so fast. But if the spinner is apparent(page is doing heavy-lifting), I decided it was better to indicate the server was working "fast"=hard rather than "slow"="lazy.

Answer (score 4):

Try setting a specific height and width on the element. Through trial and error, I found that adding:

```
#iconRepeatMain {
    width: 26px;
    height: 19px;
}
```

centers the font pretty well and seems to eliminate the wobbling. However, it's possible this is dependent on which browser is being used -- test it thoroughly.

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/pGhFX/13/

Comment: Updated again. In Chrome, 26-by-19-pixels eliminates the wobble entirely. Use your browser's web inspector to nudge the height and width until you see what you like.

Comment: Yup, with `width:25px; height:15px;` it looks great :)

Comment: But it would be much cleaner to use image.

Comment: @Kosta I don't know about 'cleaner', but it'll certainly be more reliable.

Comment: "But it would be much cleaner to use image"- @Kosta I think you could be right.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see it documented in the pages at Font Awesome's site, but the CSS source shows an icon-spin class which rotates an icon endlessly, and for your icon-repeat logo, has virtually no wobble.

```
<i class="icon-repeat icon-spin"></i>
```

...though I'm guessing it's really intended for the icon-spinner icon:

```
<i class="icon-spinner icon-spin"></i>
```

Edit: d'oh... this relies on a more recent font-awesome.css than the one in your example. So maybe the answer is just that they fixed the wobble themselves. The icon-spin class is new though.

Answer (score 0):

How I solved my issue with out-of-center rotation of icon font:
There were several issues I had to resolve:
1. size of icon: it has to be whole px size (e.g. font-size:small; makes my icon 17.5px so center is not absolute center for transformation)
2. defining display: block on icon level makes it center correctly in the middle of the parent div
3. defining exact square size of parent div (in my case button) and fixed padding made it center correctly
4. adding any text-shadow will change the size of the inner icon so it will be out of the center. Trick is to change the hover style to be the same shadow with color same as background in my case

So here is the code:

CSS:

```
button.close {
padding: 10px;
opacity: 0.8;
text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #999; 
width: 40px;
height: 40px;
}
button.close i{
font-size: 20px;
max-width: 20px;
max-height: 20px;
display: block;
}
button.close:hover {
text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #fff; 
}
/* rotation CSS*/
@keyframes anim-rotate {
0% {
-moz-transform:rotate(0);
-webkit-transform:rotate(0);
transform:rotate(0);
}
100% {
-moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
-webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
transform: rotate(360deg);
}
}
@keyframes anim-rotate-next {
0% {
-moz-transform:rotate(0);
-webkit-transform:rotate(0);
transform:rotate(0);
}
100% {
-moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
-webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
transform: rotate(360deg);
}
}
.rotate{
animation: anim-rotate-next 1s normal linear;
}
.rotate.down{
animation: anim-rotate 1s normal linear;
}
```

HTML:

```
<button type="button" class="close"><i class="lnr lnr-sync rotate"></i></button>
```

and finally JQuery for switching rotate class
JQuery:

```
$("#parentDiv").on('click', 'i.lnr-sync', function () {
// rotiraj ikonu
$(this).toggleClass("down");
});
```